# 正規表現　日付かどうかチェックしたい

Tags: c#, 正規表現

ユーザーに日付を入力させるテキストボックスがあります。
入力方法は`2021.3.1`のように年月日をドット(`.`)で区切って入力させます。(入力方法は変更不可)
入力された日付が正しいものかチェックするメソッドを作成しているのですが
その際、`*.3.1`や`*.*.*`のようにアスタリスク(`*`)で年月日を入力された場合でも日付チェックOKにしたいのですが
以下のコードではうまく動きませんでした。

解決策をご教授いただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
string date = "*.*.*";  // 入力された年月日 (現状NGになってしまう)

 if (Regex.IsMatch(date, "[0-9]{4}|[*].[1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[*].[1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]|[*]"))
 {
 　　result = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

正規表現のパターンとしては

```
^(?:[0-9]{4}|\*)\.(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]|\*)\.(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|\*)$
```

ぐらいでしょうか？
これをC#文字列としてソースコードに記述するには

```
@"^(?:[0-9]{4}|\*)\.(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]|\*)\.(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|\*)$"
```

もしくは

```
"^(?:[0-9]{4}|\\*)\\.(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]|\\*)\\.(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|\\*)$"
```

でしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
無事通るようになりました。